# The name 'parametros' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

Tenho o código abaixo e está dando o seguinte erro:

> The name 'sql' does not exist in the current context The name
>   'parametros' does not exist in the current context

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?
Agradeço desde já...

```
public DataSet PesquisarProtocolos(string usuarioAutenticado, long? codigoProcotolo, int? codigoMenu, string campoPesquisaDinamica, string valorPesquisaDinamica, string periodo, int? mes, int? ano, int? codigoStatus, int? codigoMotivo, int? codigoTipoRemuneracao, int? codigoGrupoContestacao, int? codigoTipoContestacao, int? codigoMotivoContestacao, bool carregarDivergentes, int? perfil = null, string parceirosGestaoCarteira = "", int codigoCargo = 0)
        {
            if ((codigoCargo == 9) || (codigoCargo == 1029) || (codigoCargo == 1030))
            { 
                //vou colocar depois o código
            }
            else if ((codigoCargo == 8) || (codigoCargo == 11)) 
            {
                //vou colocar depois o código
            }
            else
            {
                 string sql = string.Format(@"
                SELECT DISTINCT     
                       C.[COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO]
                      ,C.[COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO_RELACIONADO]
                      ,C.[QTD_LINHAS_PROCESSADAS]
                      ,C.[QTD_LINHAS_DIVERGENTES]
                      ,(SELECT TOP 1 LOGIN FROM ADM_USUARIO U WHERE U.cod_usuario = C.COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL) [COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL]
                      ,C.[DSC_PERIODO_PAGAMENTO]
                      ,C.[NUM_ANO_PAGAMENTO]
                      ,C.[NUM_MES_PAGAMENTO]
                      ,C.[COD_ESPELHO_ASSOCIACAO]
                     ,C.[COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO]
                      ,C.[NUM_MES_REFERENCIA]
                      ,C.[NUM_ANO_REFERENCIA]
                      ,C.[COD_PARCEIRO_REFERENCIA]
                      ,C.[DT_CRIACAO]
                      ,C.[DSC_ARQUIVO]
                      ,C.[DT_ATUALIZACAO]
                      ,TR.DESC_TIPO_REMUNERACAO  
                      ,SP.desc_status_processo
                      ,AM.desc_motivo
                      ,DATEDIFF(DAY, HP.DT_HISTORICO, GETDATE()) AS SLA
                      ,P.cnpj_parceiro
                      ,P.nom_razao_social
                      ,E.NUM_MES_COMISSAO
                      ,E.NUM_ANO_COMISSAO
                    ,case when  c.cod_tipo_remuneracao=4 then 'Mensal' else T.desc_tipo_quinzena end AS PERIODO
            FROM [CON_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO] C
            LEFT JOIN REM_ESPELHO E ON E.COD_ESPELHO = CAST(C.COD_ESPELHO_ASSOCIACAO AS BIGINT)
            LEFT JOIN GAC_TIPO_QUINZENA T ON T.cod_tipo_quinzena = E.cod_periodo_Comissao
            INNER JOIN ADM_TIPO_REMUNERACAO TR ON TR.cod_tipo_remuneracao = C.cod_tipo_remuneracao
            INNER JOIN CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO HP ON HP.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO = C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO  AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA is null 
            INNER JOIN ADM_STATUS_PROCESSO SP ON SP.cod_status_processo = HP.cod_status_processo
            INNER JOIN ADM_MOTIVO AM ON AM.cod_motivo = HP.COD_MOTIVO
            LEFT JOIN GDC_PARCEIRO P ON P.cod_parceiro = C.COD_PARCEIRO_REFERENCIA
            LEFT JOIN GDC_SEGMENTO SG ON SG.cod_segmento = P.cod_segmento
            LEFT JOIN GDC_CANAL canal ON canal.cod_canal = SG.cod_canal
            LEFT JOIN GDC_CANAL_PERFIL perfil ON perfil.cod_canal_perfil = canal.cod_canal_perfil
        WHERE   
            (C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO OR @COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL)
            AND (perfil.cod_canal_perfil = @PERFIL OR @PERFIL IS NULL)
            AND (
                @LOGIN IS NULL
                OR (COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL IS NULL OR COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL = '')
                OR (COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL IS NOT NULL AND COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL = (SELECT cod_usuario FROM ADM_USUARIO WHERE Login = @LOGIN))
                OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ADM_USUARIO where sit_libera_pedido = 1 AND Login = @LOGIN) = 1)
            AND (@COD_MENU IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (
                    SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO 
                    WHERE COD_MENU = @COD_MENU AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA IS NULL 
                    AND (DATEPART(MONTH,DT_HISTORICO) = @MES OR @MES IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(YEAR,DT_HISTORICO) = @ANO OR @ANO IS NULL) 
                ))
            {0}
            AND (@PERIODO IS NULL  OR @PERIODO = DSC_PERIODO_PAGAMENTO)
            AND (C.COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO = @COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO OR @COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO IS NULL)
            AND (@COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM WHERE COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO))
            AND (@COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM WHERE COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO))
            AND (@COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM WHERE COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO))
            AND (@COD_STATUS IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO WHERE COD_STATUS_PROCESSO = @COD_STATUS AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA IS NULL))
            AND (@COD_MOTIVO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO WHERE COD_MOTIVO = @COD_MOTIVO AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA IS NULL))
            AND (@CARREGAR_DIVERGENTES = 1 OR (@CARREGAR_DIVERGENTES = 0 AND C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (select cod_protocolo_contestacao from CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM where sit_divergente = 0)))
             ", string.IsNullOrEmpty(parceirosGestaoCarteira) ? "" : string.Format("AND P.cod_parceiro IN ({0})", parceirosGestaoCarteira)); ;

            Dictionary<string, object> parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valorPesquisaDinamica) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(campoPesquisaDinamica))
            {
                sql += string.Format("AND (CAST({0} AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%' + @VALOR_PESQUISA_DINAMICA + '%')", campoPesquisaDinamica, valorPesquisaDinamica);
                parametros.Add("@VALOR_PESQUISA_DINAMICA", valorPesquisaDinamica);
            }

            sql += "  ORDER BY SLA DESC ";

            parametros.Add("@LOGIN", usuarioAutenticado ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@PERFIL", perfil ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO", codigoProcotolo ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@CARREGAR_DIVERGENTES", carregarDivergentes ? 1 : 0);
            parametros.Add("@COD_MENU", codigoMenu ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@PERIODO", periodo ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@MES", mes ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@ANO", ano ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_STATUS", codigoStatus ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_MOTIVO", codigoMotivo ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO", codigoTipoRemuneracao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO", codigoGrupoContestacao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO", codigoTipoContestacao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            parametros.Add("@COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO", codigoMotivoContestacao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

        }

        using (TFPlusDO db = GetConnection<TFPlusDO>())
        {
            return db.Query(sql, parametros);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @GWER Desculpe, nós dois editamos ao mesmo tempo e o sistema por algum motivo deu preferência à minha edição. Se você tiver alguma outra edição a sugerir, sinta-se a vontade.

Comment: O sql tá fora do escopo do using. Deveria ter declarado o `sql` fora do else, o mesmo com o `parametros`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado pelo comentário, mas a minha edição foi basicamente a mesma que a sua! De qualquer jeito agradeço a preocupação, e sua edição está ótima assim. ;)

Comment: @Patrick escreve uma resposta sobre isso.

Answer (score 2):

No C# (e em muitas outras linguagens), existem os **escopos**, que são contextos que delimitam a área de atuação de uma variável, por exemplo.

Se você tentar fazer

```
public String Foo(int y, int x) //escopo externo
{
    if (x == y) //escopo interno
    {
        String z = "Igual";
    }
    return z;
}
```

Irá dar erro, pois o `z` está em um escopo mais interno que o `return`.

Em C#, um truque que você pode usar para não esquecer isso é: tudo o que estiver declarado dentro das chaves, não pode ser referenciado fora delas.

---

O problema no seu código é que você simplesmente declarou as variáveis `sql` e `parametros` em escopos diferentes.

Puxe-as para um nível acima, fora do else, e tudo ficará ok.

```
public DataSet PesquisarProtocolos(argumentos...)
{
    String sql;
    Dictionary<string, object> parametros;
}
```

Comment: Boa visualização.

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim que resolverá o seu problema:

*Observe que eu apenas inserir as variáveis no inicio do método. Dependendo da sua aplicação, talvez seja necessário fazer uma verificação nas variáveis.

```
public DataSet PesquisarProtocolos(string usuarioAutenticado, long? codigoProcotolo, int? codigoMenu, string campoPesquisaDinamica, string valorPesquisaDinamica, string periodo, int? mes, int? ano, int? codigoStatus, int? codigoMotivo, int? codigoTipoRemuneracao, int? codigoGrupoContestacao, int? codigoTipoContestacao, int? codigoMotivoContestacao, bool carregarDivergentes, int? perfil = null, string parceirosGestaoCarteira = "", int codigoCargo = 0)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    string sql = string.Empty;
    if ((codigoCargo == 9) || (codigoCargo == 1029) || (codigoCargo == 1030))
    {
        //vou colocar depois o código
    }
    else if ((codigoCargo == 8) || (codigoCargo == 11))
    {
        //vou colocar depois o código
    }
    else
    {
        sql = string.Format(@"
    SELECT DISTINCT     
            C.[COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO]
            ,C.[COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO_RELACIONADO]
            ,C.[QTD_LINHAS_PROCESSADAS]
            ,C.[QTD_LINHAS_DIVERGENTES]
            ,(SELECT TOP 1 LOGIN FROM ADM_USUARIO U WHERE U.cod_usuario = C.COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL) [COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL]
            ,C.[DSC_PERIODO_PAGAMENTO]
            ,C.[NUM_ANO_PAGAMENTO]
            ,C.[NUM_MES_PAGAMENTO]
            ,C.[COD_ESPELHO_ASSOCIACAO]
            ,C.[COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO]
            ,C.[NUM_MES_REFERENCIA]
            ,C.[NUM_ANO_REFERENCIA]
            ,C.[COD_PARCEIRO_REFERENCIA]
            ,C.[DT_CRIACAO]
            ,C.[DSC_ARQUIVO]
            ,C.[DT_ATUALIZACAO]
            ,TR.DESC_TIPO_REMUNERACAO  
            ,SP.desc_status_processo
            ,AM.desc_motivo
            ,DATEDIFF(DAY, HP.DT_HISTORICO, GETDATE()) AS SLA
            ,P.cnpj_parceiro
            ,P.nom_razao_social
            ,E.NUM_MES_COMISSAO
            ,E.NUM_ANO_COMISSAO
        ,case when  c.cod_tipo_remuneracao=4 then 'Mensal' else T.desc_tipo_quinzena end AS PERIODO
FROM [CON_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO] C
LEFT JOIN REM_ESPELHO E ON E.COD_ESPELHO = CAST(C.COD_ESPELHO_ASSOCIACAO AS BIGINT)
LEFT JOIN GAC_TIPO_QUINZENA T ON T.cod_tipo_quinzena = E.cod_periodo_Comissao
INNER JOIN ADM_TIPO_REMUNERACAO TR ON TR.cod_tipo_remuneracao = C.cod_tipo_remuneracao
INNER JOIN CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO HP ON HP.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO = C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO  AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA is null 
INNER JOIN ADM_STATUS_PROCESSO SP ON SP.cod_status_processo = HP.cod_status_processo
INNER JOIN ADM_MOTIVO AM ON AM.cod_motivo = HP.COD_MOTIVO
LEFT JOIN GDC_PARCEIRO P ON P.cod_parceiro = C.COD_PARCEIRO_REFERENCIA
LEFT JOIN GDC_SEGMENTO SG ON SG.cod_segmento = P.cod_segmento
LEFT JOIN GDC_CANAL canal ON canal.cod_canal = SG.cod_canal
LEFT JOIN GDC_CANAL_PERFIL perfil ON perfil.cod_canal_perfil = canal.cod_canal_perfil
WHERE   
(C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO OR @COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL)
AND (perfil.cod_canal_perfil = @PERFIL OR @PERFIL IS NULL)
AND (
    @LOGIN IS NULL
    OR (COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL IS NULL OR COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL = '')
    OR (COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL IS NOT NULL AND COD_USUARIO_RESPONSAVEL = (SELECT cod_usuario FROM ADM_USUARIO WHERE Login = @LOGIN))
    OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ADM_USUARIO where sit_libera_pedido = 1 AND Login = @LOGIN) = 1)
AND (@COD_MENU IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (
        SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO 
        WHERE COD_MENU = @COD_MENU AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA IS NULL 
        AND (DATEPART(MONTH,DT_HISTORICO) = @MES OR @MES IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(YEAR,DT_HISTORICO) = @ANO OR @ANO IS NULL) 
    ))
{0}
AND (@PERIODO IS NULL  OR @PERIODO = DSC_PERIODO_PAGAMENTO)
AND (C.COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO = @COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO OR @COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO IS NULL)
AND (@COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM WHERE COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO))
AND (@COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM WHERE COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO))
AND (@COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM WHERE COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO = @COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO))
AND (@COD_STATUS IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO WHERE COD_STATUS_PROCESSO = @COD_STATUS AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA IS NULL))
AND (@COD_MOTIVO IS NULL OR C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (SELECT COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO FROM CON_CONTESTACAO_HISTORICO_PROCESSO WHERE COD_MOTIVO = @COD_MOTIVO AND DT_MUDANCA_FILA IS NULL))
AND (@CARREGAR_DIVERGENTES = 1 OR (@CARREGAR_DIVERGENTES = 0 AND C.COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO IN (select cod_protocolo_contestacao from CON_CONTESTACAO_ESPELHO_ITEM where sit_divergente = 0)))
    ", string.IsNullOrEmpty(parceirosGestaoCarteira) ? "" : string.Format("AND P.cod_parceiro IN ({0})", parceirosGestaoCarteira)); ;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valorPesquisaDinamica) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(campoPesquisaDinamica))
        {
            sql += string.Format("AND (CAST({0} AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%' + @VALOR_PESQUISA_DINAMICA + '%')", campoPesquisaDinamica, valorPesquisaDinamica);
            parametros.Add("@VALOR_PESQUISA_DINAMICA", valorPesquisaDinamica);
        }

        sql += "  ORDER BY SLA DESC ";

        parametros.Add("@LOGIN", usuarioAutenticado ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@PERFIL", perfil ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_PROTOCOLO_CONTESTACAO", codigoProcotolo ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@CARREGAR_DIVERGENTES", carregarDivergentes ? 1 : 0);
        parametros.Add("@COD_MENU", codigoMenu ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@PERIODO", periodo ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@MES", mes ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@ANO", ano ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_STATUS", codigoStatus ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_MOTIVO", codigoMotivo ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_TIPO_REMUNERACAO", codigoTipoRemuneracao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_GRUPO_CONTESTACAO", codigoGrupoContestacao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_TIPO_CONTESTACAO", codigoTipoContestacao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        parametros.Add("@COD_MOTIVO_CONTESTACAO", codigoMotivoContestacao ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

    }

    using (TFPlusDO db = GetConnection<TFPlusDO>())
    {
        return db.Query(sql, parametros);
    }

}
```