# Como extrair uma variável de dentro de uma função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supondo que eu utilize a seguinte função no .js... E dentro dela tenha algumas variáveis.

```
$(document).on("load", function(){
    var Variavel1= "um";
    var Variavel2= "dois";
    var Variavel3= "tres";
    var Variavel4= "quatro";
})
```

Como eu faço pra utilizar qualquer uma dessas variáveis fora dessa função?

```
$(document).on("load", function(){
    var Variavel1= "um";
    var Variavel2= "dois";
    var Variavel3= "tres";
    var Variavel4= "quatro";
})

alert(Variavel3);
```

Comment: Não é exatamente a resposta pra sua pergunta, mas [essa dúvida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/1333), pode te acrescentar informações interessantes. (:

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58621/6077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

existem duas maneiras

1 - Declarando fora. Dessa maneira o código fica mais simples de entender e você pode controlar os escopos de forma explicita.

```js
var foo; // declaração fora
function teste() {
  foo = 'valor'; // sem "var"
}
teste(); // executa função
alert(foo); // exibe "valor"
```

2 - Atribuindo pelo `window`. As variáveis declaradas com `var` ou acessadas no escopo global (fora de funções) são propriedades do objeto `window`, então você pode atribuir dessa maneira

```js
function teste() {
  window.foo = 'valor'; // atribui como propriedade de "window"
}
teste(); // executa função
alert(foo); // acessa sem "window." - exibe "valor"
```

Answer (score 4):

As variaveis criadas dentro da função só existe nesse escopo, ou seja dentro da função.
Para acessa-las tanto dentro quanto fora, deve-se cria-las fora da função dentro do escopo geral ou seja:
Exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/5zc3yqks/

Como você pode ver no meu exemplo funciona, mas no seu caso, tem que ver o seguinte, as instruções que estão dentro do "on" são executadas antes da declaração da própria variável. Ou seja, no escopo do ON a variavel nem existe ainda, dai ele vai criar e setar o valor, depois ele sai do escopo do ON e cria a variavel de novo, tirando o valor que foi associado.

Answer (score 3):

Dentro de uma função você tem um **escopo local**.

Para acessar uma variável de escopo local dentro de outro local, o único jeito que eu vejo é **retornando a variável que você deseja**. Assim você chama a função e obtem a variável.

**Ou senão**, você declara as variáveis fora das funções. **Escopo global**. Assim você pode acessá-las em qualquer função.

Answer (score 2):

Quando precisar declarar uma variável global dentro de uma função, deve especificar a profundidade de onde o objeto será instanciado.

Para declarar dentro do escopo global, declare com o prefixo `window.`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {

        window.variavel1= "um";
        var variavel2= "dois";
        var variavel3= "tres";

    });

    function foo()
    {
        console.log('test: '+ variavel1);
    /*
observe que variavel1 está no escopo global. 
tente executar console.log('test: '+ variavel2); e obterá erro de variável indefinida pois está dentro do escobo da *lambda function*.
*/
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="button" value="click me!" onclick="foo();" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você nunca conseguirá acessar os valores externamente para uma ***Lambda function***, dessas do tipo do **jQuery** que executam tudo internamente, entretanto, você pode criar uma subfunção que tenha uma saída externa conforme este exemplo:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var variavel1= "um";
    var variavel2= "dois";
    var variavel3= "tres";
    var variavel4= "quatro";
    variaveisSaida(variavel1,variavel2,variavel3,variavel4);
  });

function variaveisSaida(val1,val2,val3,val4) {
    console.log('estou aqui fora: '+val1+','+val2+','+val3+','+val4);
    alert(val1+','+val2+','+val3+','+val4);
}
```

Você também pode declarar uma variável com um valor externamente e utilizá-lo dentro de seu escopo, mas qualquer alteração que fizer nesta variável, só será executada internamente, para ter uma saída, é preciso ter um método externo que capture internamente essa saída.

Answer (score -1):

Declare as variáveis fora da função...elas só são reconhecidas dentro da função porque foram declaradas dentro da função